# Filter on entire object AND specific key in object with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Ok. So I know that I can filter against all keys in an object like this:

```
<input ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search">
```

And on two specific keys in an object like this:

```
<input ng-model="search.name">
<input ng-model="search.contact">
<div ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search">
```

But what if I wanted the second input to filter against the entire object? Meaning that the value of the first input only matched against the key `name` but the second input matched against the values in all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Filter twice.

```
<input ng-model="search.name">
<input ng-model="search.contact">
<div ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search.name | filter:search.contact">
```

This filters by name and then passes those results through the filter by contact. If you want results matching 'name' *or* 'contact' then you'll need to just write your own filter.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. But thanks anyway! Ended up writing my own filter.